# Foreign key referencing multiple tables error

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL and trying to create a DB for a theatre booking system. But creating the following table gives an error.

```
CREATE TABLE Booking (
    Email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PerfDate DATE,
    PerfTime TIME,
    RowNumber CHAR(3),
    FOREIGN KEY (PerfDate, PerfTime) REFERENCES Performance (PerfDate, PerfTime),
    FOREIGN KEY RowNumber REFERENCES Seat (RowNumber),
    );

INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ('ZP@email.com',DATE '2017-11-01',TIME '19:00:00','Z18');
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ('ZP@email.com',DATE '2017-11-01',TIME '19:00:00','Z19');
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ('Jane.Dot@live.com',DATE '2017-11-01',TIME '19:00:00','Z16');
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ('Jane.Dot@live.com',DATE '2017-11-05',TIME '13:00:00','U20');
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ('Jane.Dot@live.com',DATE '2017-11-05',TIME '13:00:00','U19');
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ('Mike.Stand@email.com',DATE '2017-11-05',TIME '13:00:00','X13');
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ('Mike.Stand@email.com',DATE '2017-11-05',TIME '13:00:00','X14');
INSERT INTO Booking VALUES ('qvf3@live.com',DATE '2017-11-05',TIME '13:00:00','Z19');


ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES Seat (RowNumber),
)' at line 7
```

Am I setting FKs incorrectly?

Comment: the "," in "REFERENCES Seat (RowNumber)," is too much... the error is rather clear, also check the syntax of such statement here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp
btw: shouldn't you add a primary key?

Comment: I've tried removing the comma and get the same error. According to the relational schema given to us the primary key should ALSO be PerfDate, PerfTime, RowNumber.
Can I define the FK using:
FOREIGN KEY (PerfDate, PerfTime, RowNumber) REFERENCES Performance (PerfDate, PerfTime), Seat (RowNumber), 
in a single statement rather than one statement? It is supposed to be a single composite foreign key.

Comment: hmm maybe the () around the fk name are required? "FOREIGN KEY (RowNumber) REFERENCES" seems like the only difference compared to this answer:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114274/how-do-i-create-a-table-with-a-two-primary-keys-of-two-foreign-keys

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the character ,[comma] in the line FOREIGN KEY RowNumber REFERENCES Seat (RowNumber),

Comment: I removed the , as you suggested but still get an error.